# how to make this fit in same line in css

Tags: css

I want Dial a food and Login,signup in the same line. Login and signup should be in right corner of the same line where dial a food stays.

```
<body>
   <div id="header">
      <h1 style="color: #FF9933; height: 25px; width: auto;">Dial A Food</h1>
          <div id="user">
             <ul class="list-inline h5 mtm user-links">
                <li class="login">
                   <a title="Log in" href="/member/login">
                      <strong>Log in</strong>
                   </a>
                </li>
                <li class="signup">
                   <a title="Sign up" href="/member/signup">
                      <strong>Sign up</strong>
                   </a>
                </li>
           </ul>
       </div>
```

Since i started learning now only, please help me.

Comment: Well, your question isn't really about "login" and "signup". It's more about formatting your Lists. If you do a search related to "list styling" or of that similarity you'll find many articles on the web and most likely this website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a basic example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style media="all">
    h1, ul, li {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    h1 {float: left; color: #FF9933;}
    #user {float: right;}
    ul {list-style: none;}
    ul li {float: left; padding-left: 20px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Dial A Food</h1>
        <div id="user">
            <ul class="list-inline h5 mtm user-links">
                <li class="login">
                    <a title="Log in" href="/member/login">
                        <strong>Log in</strong>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="signup">
                    <a title="Sign up" href="/member/signup">
                        <strong>Sign up</strong>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`div`, `h1` and `li` are block elements so make it inline

```
#header, #user, h1, li{
  display:inline-block
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ugiHOraS/2/)**

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
body,html{height:100%;width:100%;margin:0;}
h1{float:left;}
#user{float:right;}
#user li{display:inline-block;}
#header{width:100%;} /* remove width from html markup */
.clr{clear:both;}
```

Clear `floats` at the end:

```
<div class="clr"></div>
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/zwE4R/1)

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper"> <div id="header">
      <h1 style="color: #FF9933; height: 25px;">Dial A Food</h1>
          <div id="user">
             <ul>
                <li> <a title="Log in" href="/member/login">                      <strong>Log in</strong>   </a>  </li>
                <li >  <a title="Sign up" href="/member/signup">
                      <strong>Sign up</strong> </a> </li>
           </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper
{
    width:700px;
}
#header , h1
{
    display:inline:block;
    float:left;
    }
#user, ul , li,a
{
    display:inline:block;
    float:right;
    padding:5px;
     list-style:none;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/WSQg3/17/)

Answer (score 0):

since your "dial a food" is in an `H1` tag, and the other two elements are within a list, they can not be on the same line without specific styling and positioning.

The `li` elements can be on the same line if you add this css to your code:

css

```
#header, #user, h1, li {
    display:inline;
    padding:10px;
}
```